# Saving user info without accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, user-interface

So, I have a website that figures out the users location when they load the page. They can change it if it's incorrect. I'd like for the next time the user comes to the page, for it to remember what they changed it to the last time they were on.

We don't have user accounts on our website (and nor do we really want them right now). How else would I be able to link to and save this information based on the user logging on.

I could use their IP address (if it's blocked fine, don't need to do it for them). Is this not a good idea to just have a linked table setup with a pair of coordinates and an IP?

I was actually going to use the same logic to link a user to all their comments that they posted on the page to have a quick "My Comments" section, by linking it to their IP.

Without accounts, using a users IP address is really the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your requirements I'd say that saving the data to a cookie seems the simplest solution.

```
Response.Cookies["location"].Value = "0.008487,0.022724";
```

The users IP may have changed by the next time they visit your site, just as much as their cookies may have been cleared.

Also, you may find that users of your site will have the same IP address especially given that there's usually a single IP address on all shared routers. (Both in the home and in the workplace).

That may be something you've accounted for and wanted? But it means that one user changing their preference would also change the preference for all users of that same IP.

I think this method is fine for your location tracking service however for the comments and any other user preferences based work I'd start thinking about user accounts.

Comment: I've never really worked with cookies before in an MVC app. How would I do that? Just save a cookie with a specific name/value pair, and try and look for it when the page loads? Can I do that within Javascript too?

Comment: You can simply add the cookie from your MVC application and then access the same cookie on both the server and client side.

Comment: How big can a cookie be? Could I have a cookie that stored a list of integers, represented each Id of a comment they have posted, so the next time they load up the site I know every single comment Id from them? I know this is way better suited towards accounts, and maybe making user accounts is the solution...

Comment: Sure, I doubt that'd take up much space especially if you just set it as a comma-delimited string of id's such as "1,10,50,20,40" etc. Just set a cookie for their location and one for their comments. It seems a flimsy way of tracking user activity though. It fits the need for the location, but for the comments I'd seriously consider the user account option.